# Exception occured processing WSGI script

Tags: python, django, apache, python-3.x, fedora

I'm trying to configure `mod_wsgi` to run with Apache so I can use Django on Apache on the same virtual host, along with the previous Apache+PHP configuration. I've been trying to run my Django app on the `http://localhost/django` address. Following is my configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/sites-available/localhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    # ServerAlias foo.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias /django /home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
    DocumentRoot /home/httpd/localhost/public_html
    ErrorLog /home/httpd/localhost/error.log
    CustomLog /home/httpd/localhost/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache
$ ls -l /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/localhost.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Jan 17 08:21 /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/localhost.conf -> /etc/httpd/sites-available/localhost.conf
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
...
# Include virtual hosts
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
$ cat /home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py 
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
$ ls -AR /home/httpd/localhost/
/home/httpd/localhost/:
django.wsgi  error.log  mysite  public_html  requests.log

/home/httpd/localhost/mysite:
db.sqlite3  manage.py  mysite

/home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite:
__init__.py  __pycache__  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py

/home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite/__pycache__:
__init__.cpython-34.pyc  settings.cpython-34.pyc  urls.cpython-34.pyc  wsgi.cpython-34.pyc

/home/httpd/localhost/public_html:
index.php
```

When I go to `http://localhost/`, I see the script `/home/httpd/localhost/public_html/index.php` run, as expected. However, when I visit `http://localhost/django`, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I get the following stack trace in `/home/httpd/localhost/error.log` (removed timestamps and other [bracketed] stuff for readability):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=16908): Target WSGI script '/home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=16908): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/httpd/localhost/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Note that the `/home/httpd/localhost/mysite/` directory was created by the `django-admin.py` script.

Also note that just running `./manage.py runserver` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't done anything to put the Django project on the Python path. As this to the top of your wsgi script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/httpd/localhost/mysite')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Add your project path to sys.path

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/httpd/localhost/mysite')  

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```